# how to get twitter more info on standart mvc application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, facebook, twitter

when i create a new mvc web site it automatically create AccountController.cs controller. in this class there is an action to login from social networks.

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl)
    {
        AuthenticationResult result = OAuthWebSecurity.VerifyAuthentication(Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl }));
        if (!result.IsSuccessful)
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ExternalLoginFailure");
        }

        if (OAuthWebSecurity.Login(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, createPersistentCookie: false))
        {
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }

        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // If the current user is logged in add the new account
            OAuthWebSecurity.CreateOrUpdateAccount(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId, User.Identity.Name);
            return RedirectToLocal(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            // User is new, ask for their desired membership name
            string loginData = OAuthWebSecurity.SerializeProviderUserId(result.Provider, result.ProviderUserId);
            ViewBag.ProviderDisplayName = OAuthWebSecurity.GetOAuthClientData(result.Provider).DisplayName;
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View("ExternalLoginConfirmation", new RegisterExternalLoginModel { UserName = result.UserName, ExternalLoginData = loginData });
        }
    }
```

i have already added twitter secret and api id. But on callback i have only the username. but i want the user real name information too.

exact same thing is neccessary for google and facebook login too.

Answer (score 0):

Most social network APIs have an endpoint for obtaining additional user information once they are authenticated, using the OAuth token. For example for Twitter the endpoint is https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/account/verify_credentials - you have to send the token and token secret (which you get from the OAuth provider upon authentication) and you will receive the user information that Twitter provides.